# Error while running sonar-scanner on mac machine

Tags: ios, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have installed the latest version of sonarqube 7.0 on my mac machine and trying to configure my iOS Swift project.

I am getting the following error while running the command sonar-scanner

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: org/sonar/api/measures/PersistenceMode
ERROR: Caused by: org.sonar.api.measures.PersistenceMode
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR - Command 'sonar-scanner ' failed with error code: 1
```

Note: Using the latest plugin  **backelite-sonar-swift-plugin-0.3.5.jar**

Answer (score 1):

The above issues has a quick fix in the below link,
https://github.com/Hugal31/sonar-swift/tree/fix/persistence-mode

Download the plugin and replace with the old version. It might help you.